# How do I exclude a child element from an svg filter applied to the parent element, without changing the elements structure?

Tags: css, svg-filters

Z-index seem to have no effect either in this regard.
I cannot add or remove elements, other than adding a pseudo element.
The image is uploaded from the Wordpress backend, and it's changing in every post so I cannot store that in a pseudo element.
The parent container has a background image and there is a child element on the top of it, with text.
I applied the svg filter to the parent container, since it cannot be applied to img tags.
But I don't want the svg filter to affect the text.

Comment: please add some minimum [reproducible exmaple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can't exclude a child element from the effects of a filter applied to its parent. You might be able to apply a different filter on the text to reverse the effect of the filter on the parent - but that's going to be very dependent on what the filter does. For example, you can't reverse the effect of a blur.